# android copy file from sd to assets

Tags: android, assets, android-assets

Is is possible to copy a file from sd to assets ???

I don't think so...
But you all a lot more brainier than I am ;)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the assets folder is read-only.

Comment: Moreover, no folder from apk is writable.

Answer (score 0):

Assets folder is read only. You can not write into any folder which are included in the APK file.